# Как узнать ID пользователя ВКонтакте, зашедшего на мой сайт?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я создал приложение ВКонтакте. Вывел виджет комментариев (например).
На виджете фото и имя человека ВКонтакте.

Вопрос: как мне узнать ID пользователя, чтобы потом отослать его на сервер?

В общем нужно знать, кто посещал мой сайт. Виджет как-то узнаёт авторизованного пользователя — значит и я смогу сделать подобное. Только я не могу найти сам кусок кода, чтобы узнавать и отсылать ID.

Как это сделать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Есть куча сервисов(платных), которые дают свой джаваскрипт код- его внедряешь и на сервисе видишь пользователе. Причём пользователь ничего не делает и не даёт никаких согласий для приложения. Вот такое и хочется сделать

Comment: Скорее всего, они пользуются известной уязвимостью и при этом нарушают условия использования ВК. Такая вот оговорка. А пользователи, на самом деле, кое-что делают, но без намерения это сделать. Примерно в этом и заключается нарушение.

Comment: @RakzinRoman, в 99% являющихся просто разводом. А в 1% - обманным путем(кликджекинг) получающих у пользователей авторизацию приложения.